# Why the limit on manager mound visits?

Tags: rules, baseball

I recall that Don Mattingly was [forced to remove](http://www.baseball-reference.com/blog/archives/7470) his pitcher due to two mound meetings in an inning. I've read [articles](http://sports.espn.go.com/mlb/playoffs/2009/news/story?id=4617458) that indicate that a limit was placed on manager-led mound meetings to speed up the game.

The MLB [rule reference](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/official_info/official_rules/pitcher_8.jsp) (8.06):

> **8.06** A professional league shall adopt the following rule pertaining to the visit of the manager or coach to the pitcher:
>
> (a) This rule
>   limits the number of trips a manager or coach may make to any one
>   pitcher in any one inning;
>
> (b) A second trip to the same pitcher in
>   the same inning will cause this pitcher's automatic removal;
>
> (c) The
>   manager or coach is prohibited from making a second visit to the mound
>   while the same batter is at bat, but
>
> (d) if a pinch-hitter is
>   substituted for this batter, the manager or coach may make a second
>   visit to the mound, but must remove the pitcher. A manager or coach is
>   considered to have concluded his visit to the mound when he leaves the
>   18-foot circle surrounding the pitcher's rubber.

Are there any historical reasons that caused this rule to be put in place?

Comment: Arguably, in the Don Mattingly case, he was making a second trip while the same batter was at bat, which should have been prohibited by rule (b) to begin with before rule (c) would have come into effect.

Comment: How long before umpire breaks up meeting at the mound-minutes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule is in place so that a manager can't keep coming out and slowing down the game. 1. It annoys everyone 2. He could be intentionally taking his time so that a pitcher in the bullpen can warm up.

Comment: Point 2 is very plausible, although paying customers probably would prefer point 1!

Answer (score 5):

This was at least in place when I was a child and first watching baseball games in the mid 1980's.  [This person](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090823105536AASTt3V) says early 1970's.  [This edition](http://books.google.com/books?id=bi0DAAAAMBAJ&pg=PT30&lpg=PT30&dq=baseball%20limiting%20visits%20to%20the%20mound%201971&source=bl&ots=9l4MimGFSA&sig=-nNxUQaTiNR2IS3e8RTX8nfbKKM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OjM8T4O_EIXe0QH68eScCw&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Baseball Digest from 1986 had the rule listed at the bottom of a page, but I'm not sure if that's to simply convey the rule or to identify rule changes that enacted in the year.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe previous editions of the official MLB rules are publicly available, so I was not able to check when this particular rule was first enacted. All I can prove is that it existed as of [2006](http://78pyc.org/rules_policies/baseball_rules/MLB%20Rules%207-06.pdf).

My guess is that this particular rule was added to speed up the pace of the game.